# How to update collections using CassandraOperations

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am looking into a sample example of using spring-data-cassandra's CassandraOperations to update a collection inside a cassandra table.
Please share as I am finding hard to get it right. Also its not available over the web.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I looked into the spring-data-cassandra's code.Currently they only provide option to replace collection via their update operation. I will look to extend that and provide a API for collections upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Here's a selfcontained example using CQL3. Porting this to spring using a java cassandra driver shouldn't be complicated.

```sql
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1 };
cqlsh> CREATE COLUMNFAMILY test.example (name text PRIMARY KEY, emails list<text>);
cqlsh> UPDATE test.example SET emails = ['fake@mail.com'] where name='lyuben';
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM test.example;

 name   | emails
--------+-------------------
 lyuben | ['fake@mail.com']

(1 rows)
cqlsh> UPDATE test.example SET emails = ['not@real.net'] + emails where name='lyuben';
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM test.example;                                              
 name   | emails
--------+-----------------------------------
 lyuben | ['not@real.net', 'fake@mail.com']

(1 rows)
cqlsh> UPDATE test.example SET emails = emails + ['maybe@legit.cc'] where name='lyuben';
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM test.example;                                              
 name   | emails
--------+-----------------------------------------------------
 lyuben | ['not@real.net', 'fake@mail.com', 'maybe@legit.cc']

(1 rows)
```

[DOCS here](https://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_list_t.html) and here are some on the [other collections](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_collections_c.html).

The only thing to note is that it makes a difference whether you append the new collection element at the beginning of the statement or at the end:

```sql
// post-append
['not@real.net'] + emails
['not@real.net', 'fake@mail.com']
// pre-append
emails = emails + ['maybe@legit.cc']
['not@real.net', 'fake@mail.com', 'maybe@legit.cc']
```

Comment: Thanks Lyuben, i know how its done via datastax java driver as well as cql, but i was looking for something inside spring-data-cassandra. Turns out the support is not there yet.